# Even after hiding everything from Google Map using Json to style, a building (Blok M Square) stays visible

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

I am using a json file to style Google Map for my android app like explained in google docs [json file to style Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling). There is no lag in the map while dragging except for one place i.e., **Blok M Square, South Jakarta City, Jakarta, Indonesia**. Whenever this building comes into view, lagging starts and as soon as this building gets out of the view there is no lagging. So I wanted to hide this building completely to avoid the lagging effect. I tried setting the visibility of the landscape feature as off but this building stays visible. I also tried this json file:

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Everything on the map becomes hidden but the **Blok M Square** building is still visible and the same painful lag can be experienced. I am not sure what is going wrong here. Can anyone help in making that building invisible or help in reducing the lag while dragging on the google map when this building is visible?

[**A screenshot of the map after applying the above JSON**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkprw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the indoors of complex buildings like malls are still visible even if you turn visibility of everything as off in the maps_style.json file. so to turn off the visibility of the indoors you can do this in your activity:

```
map.isIndoorEnabled = false
```

Figured this a bit late.